# Install Lineage OS on Samsung Galaxy S4 and S5, heimdall problems

Tags: rom-flashing, samsung-galaxy-s-4, stock-android, samsung-galaxy-s-5, lineageos

I'm trying to install Lineage OS onto my Samsung Galaxy S4 and S5, following the instructions on https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/jfltexx/install

I've successfully installed Lineage to an S4 before, using these instructions, so I don't understand what's going on.

Both S4 and S5 exhibit the same issue.

I'm stuck at a very early stage (step 4): Instead of 'Replace Driver' I get the caption 'Reinstall Driver' on the button (Zadig v2.0.0.147). I figure that's because I did it before and it's using the same driver (also for the S5???). So perhaps that's fine.

In the instructions there is nothing about changing the target driver and I can install any of them successfully. However, none of the options work when getting to the next step, running `heimdall print-pit`

Here is the result for each driver:

**WinUSB v6.1.7600.16385**

```
Initialising connection...
Detecting device...
      Manufacturer: "Sasmsung"
           Product: "MSM8960"

            length: 18
      device class: 2
               S/N: 0
           VID:PID: 04E8:685D
         bcdDevice: 0100
   iMan:iProd:iSer: 1:2:0
          nb confs: 1

interface[0].altsetting[0]: num endpoints = 1
   Class.SubClass.Protocol: 02.02.01
       endpoint[0].address: 82
           max packet size: 0010
          polling interval: 09

interface[1].altsetting[0]: num endpoints = 2
   Class.SubClass.Protocol: 0A.00.00
       endpoint[0].address: 81
           max packet size: 0200
          polling interval: 00
       endpoint[1].address: 01
           max packet size: 0200
          polling interval: 00
Claiming interface...
Setting up interface...

Initialising protocol...
WARNING: Control transfer #1 failed. Result: -9
WARNING: Control transfer #2 failed. Result: -9
WARNING: Control transfer #3 failed. Result: -9
WARNING: Control transfer #4 failed. Result: -9
WARNING: Control transfer #5 failed. Result: -9
WARNING: Control transfer #6 failed. Result: -9
libusbx: error [windows_transfer_callback] detected I/O error 87: [87] The param
eter is incorrect.
ERROR: Failed to send data: "ODIN"
Releasing device interface...
```

**libusb0 (v1.2.5.0)**

```
Initialising connection...
Detecting device...
      Manufacturer: "Sasmsung"
           Product: "MSM8960"

            length: 18
      device class: 2
               S/N: 0
           VID:PID: 04E8:685D
         bcdDevice: 0100
   iMan:iProd:iSer: 1:2:0
          nb confs: 1

interface[0].altsetting[0]: num endpoints = 1
   Class.SubClass.Protocol: 02.02.01
       endpoint[0].address: 82
           max packet size: 0010
          polling interval: 09

interface[1].altsetting[0]: num endpoints = 2
   Class.SubClass.Protocol: 0A.00.00
       endpoint[0].address: 81
           max packet size: 0200
          polling interval: 00
       endpoint[1].address: 01
           max packet size: 0200
          polling interval: 00
Claiming interface...
Setting up interface...

Initialising protocol...
WARNING: Control transfer #1 failed. Result: -1
WARNING: Control transfer #2 failed. Result: -1
WARNING: Control transfer #3 failed. Result: -1
WARNING: Control transfer #4 failed. Result: -1
WARNING: Control transfer #5 failed. Result: -1
WARNING: Control transfer #6 failed. Result: -1
Protocol initialisation successful.

Beginning session...

Some devices may take up to 2 minutes to respond.
Please be patient!

Session begun.

Downloading device's PIT file...
ERROR: libusb error -7 whilst sending packet. Retrying...
ERROR: libusb error -7 whilst sending packet. Retrying...
ERROR: libusb error -7 whilst sending packet. Retrying...
ERROR: libusb error -7 whilst sending packet. Retrying...
ERROR: libusb error -7 whilst sending packet. Retrying...
ERROR: libusb error -7 whilst sending packet.
ERROR: Failed to send request to end PIT file transfer!
ERROR: Failed to download PIT file!
Ending session...
ERROR: libusb error -7 whilst sending packet. Retrying...
ERROR: libusb error -7 whilst sending packet. Retrying...
ERROR: libusb error -7 whilst sending packet. Retrying...
ERROR: libusb error -7 whilst sending packet. Retrying...
ERROR: libusb error -7 whilst sending packet. Retrying...
ERROR: libusb error -7 whilst sending packet.
ERROR: Failed to send end session packet!
Releasing device interface...
```

**libusbK v3.0.4.0**

```
Initialising connection...
Detecting device...
      Manufacturer: "Sasmsung"
           Product: "MSM8960"

            length: 18
      device class: 2
               S/N: 0
           VID:PID: 04E8:685D
         bcdDevice: 0100
   iMan:iProd:iSer: 1:2:0
          nb confs: 1

interface[0].altsetting[0]: num endpoints = 1
   Class.SubClass.Protocol: 02.02.01
       endpoint[0].address: 82
           max packet size: 0010
          polling interval: 09

interface[1].altsetting[0]: num endpoints = 2
   Class.SubClass.Protocol: 0A.00.00
       endpoint[0].address: 81
           max packet size: 0200
          polling interval: 00
       endpoint[1].address: 01
           max packet size: 0200
          polling interval: 00
Claiming interface...
Setting up interface...

Initialising protocol...
WARNING: Control transfer #1 failed. Result: -9
WARNING: Control transfer #2 failed. Result: -9
WARNING: Control transfer #3 failed. Result: -9
WARNING: Control transfer #4 failed. Result: -9
WARNING: Control transfer #5 failed. Result: -9
WARNING: Control transfer #6 failed. Result: -9
Protocol initialisation successful.

Beginning session...

Some devices may take up to 2 minutes to respond.
Please be patient!

Session begun.

Downloading device's PIT file...
ERROR: libusb error -7 whilst sending packet. Retrying...
ERROR: libusb error -7 whilst sending packet. Retrying...
ERROR: libusb error -7 whilst sending packet. Retrying...
ERROR: libusb error -7 whilst sending packet. Retrying...
ERROR: libusb error -7 whilst sending packet. Retrying...
ERROR: libusb error -7 whilst sending packet.
ERROR: Failed to send request to end PIT file transfer!
ERROR: Failed to download PIT file!
Ending session...
ERROR: libusb error -7 whilst sending packet. Retrying...
ERROR: libusb error -7 whilst sending packet. Retrying...
ERROR: libusb error -7 whilst sending packet. Retrying...
ERROR: libusb error -7 whilst sending packet. Retrying...
ERROR: libusb error -7 whilst sending packet. Retrying...
ERROR: libusb error -7 whilst sending packet.
ERROR: Failed to send end session packet!
Releasing device interface...
```

I've tried this on another Windows machine as well and I get the same issue. So between two computers and two phones I always get stuck in the same place. That only leaves the root of the problem to sit between back of the chair and the keyboard - what am I doing wrongly?

Further research suggests USB driver problems, but that points back to Zadig/heimdall, doesn't it?

Comment: You have a Windows machine? Ditch Heimdall, use Odin. The former is open-source while the latter is proprietary, and that's part of why the guide recommends the former, but to end users the latter is way easier to use.

Comment: Now that works! Great stuff, you are a king @AndyYan!

Comment: Cool, I'll move it to a short answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're on a Windows machine, there's no need to mess with Heimdall - use Odin instead. It's proprietary software but works almost out-of-the-box (as long as you have the official USB driver installed).

[Odin3 v3.13.1](https://dl2018.sammobile.com/Odin3-v3.13.1.zip) (download supplied by SamMobile)